# Is there any manifold (probably Riemannian) that has the feature of "path conservation"?

Tags: integration, geometry, analysis, riemannian-geometry, symmetry

By the above,I mean that is there a manifold where one can define a functional on a curve such that that curve may be equivalent to many other curves whose individual functionals sum up to that of the original curve?
Pls pardon my ignorance....but I've been trying to check if there's a mathematically formal approach to this.Thank u in advance

Comment: This sounds a lot like the length functional? Let $M$ be a riemannian manifold with metric $\langle, \rangle$ and $\gamma : I := (a,b) \to M$ be a curve on $M$ and
$$
L[\gamma] := \int_a^b \langle \gamma'(t), \gamma'(t) \rangle dt
$$
be the length functional. Then for all partitions $a=:x_0<x_1<...<x_{n+1}:=b$ of $I$ we have $L[\gamma] = \sum_{i=0}^n L[\gamma|_{(x_i,x_{i+1})}]$. Is this kinda like what you had in mind?

Comment: Yeah probably......I'm just trying to understand a Riemannian space that is such that if I have say an infinitesimally small object moving along a straight line (say)...then I can get the same situation by getting that same object to move along many different curves simultaneously in such a way that there exists a certain "conserved functional" such that the sum of this functional along the many different curves is equal to that of the straight line

Comment: Hmm, I think you could construct a bunch of functionals like that by considering essentially variations of some curve. Let's say we have some curve $\gamma : I = (a,b) \to \mathbb{R}^n$ then we can consider this the straight line path of your small object. If you now take any curve  $\delta \gamma : I \to \mathbb{R}^n$ with $\delta \gamma (a) = \delta \gamma(b) = 0$ then the curve $\gamma + \delta \gamma$ is an alternative route for your small object. And now you can just be creative and think of some functionals?

Comment: Like for example taking the "maximum deviation" of the varied curve from the original should give you a functional that's 0 for $\gamma$ and conserve this if you decompose $\gamma$ into $\gamma + \delta \gamma$ and $\gamma - \delta \gamma$ etc.

Comment: Your idea is nice tho but it looks more like it's describing some sort of geodesic......recall that I intend that the straight line sorta "splits" into multiple curves such that if u sum up the functionals of these multiple curves you get that of the straight line.......But I still like your idea